# DateDiff Bigint Datetime in Redshift for Min Difference

Tags: amazon-redshift

How to Take Datediff from 20200211000000 AND 20200211001820 in Amazon redshift as Looking the Data we can say there is difference of 3 Min How can this be Achieve Using Query

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(minute,TO_TIMESTAMP('20200211000000','YYYYMMDDHH24MISS')::TIMESTAMP,TO_TIMESTAMP('20200211001820','YYYYMMDDHH24MISS')::TIMESTAMP);
```

The above query first formats the string to a `TIMESTAMPTZ` value and then converts it to `TIMESTAMP` as the `DATEDIFF` functions only accepts `TIMESTAMP` values as arguments.